# So does our 'week' of Private beta end

Tags: discussion, beta

Today, Tomorrow or Wednesday?  I saw the post earlier, just wondering when our Beta will finally go public, we seem to be slowing down without the influx of new users.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It apparently just ended. At least I just got the beta badge, and the site shows up in my Stack Exchange profile, which it didn't before.

Comment: Yes, the site is now in public beta.

Answer (score 5):

<s>Although we have been given an additional week to help define the site, I don't think this was meant to indicate a definite start date for public beta. The decision will have to be based on the whole private beta, including the additional week, so it doesn't make sense to try and put a definite timing on it. People who have been there for the start of other public betas may be able to give you more insight, but I would still expect it to be mainly conjecture at this stage.</s>

## We are now in public beta!!